# Determination of a probability mass function of the number of quarter ﬁnals in which two teams from the same country play against each other.

Tags: probability

I'm struggling with the last part of this question.

> In this year’s UEFA Champions League, three Spanish teams, two German teams, one Italian team, one French team and one English team reached the quarter ﬁnals. The matches in the quarter ﬁnals are determined by drawing lots, one by one. Each possible match is equally likely.
>   Let A be the event that the two German teams play against each other in the quarter ﬁnals. Let B be the event that there are two Spanish teams playing against each other in the quarter ﬁnals. Furthermore, let the random variable X be the number of quarter ﬁnals in which two teams from the same country play against each other.
>
> a)Determine $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.
>
> b)Determine $P(A|B), P(B|A), P(A \cap B), P(A \cup B), P(A - B), P(B - A)$ and $P(A^c \cap B^c)$.
>
> c)Are the events $A$ and $B$ disjoint? And are they independent? Clearly explain your answer.
>
> d)Determine the probability mass function and the expectation of the random variable $X$.

I think I got the answers to a), b) and c) but I don't exactly know how to do the probability mass function. There is this related question here [Probability of a quarter final combination](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2285176/probability-of-a-quarter-final-combination) but I want to check my work.

I think there will be 4 different parts, one where $X = 0$ (so no teams from the same country play against each other), one where $X = 1$ (there is one game in which two teams from the same country play against each other), one where $X = 2$ (there are two games in which two teams from the same country play against each other) and all other values give zero.

For $X = 1$, the probability is the union of $A$ and $B$ and for $X = 2$, the probability is the intersect of $A$ and $B$, I think.
I calculated this in the following way:
$P(A|B) = 4 \cdot \frac{2\cdot 1}{6\cdot 5} = \frac{1}{5}$
$P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)\cdot P(B) = \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{7} = \frac{3}{35}$

With this the union could be calculated as:
$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{7} + \frac{3}{7} - \frac{3}{35} = \frac{17}{35}$

Since $\sum_{} P_x(x) = 1$, I think the part of $X = 0$ should be $1 - \frac{17}{35} - \frac{3}{35} = \frac{15}{35}$.

This would make the PMF the following if I'm correct?

$$P_x(x) =
\begin{cases}
3/35,  & \text{if $x$ is 2} \\
17/35, & \text{if $x$ is 1} \\
15/35, & \text{if $x$ is 0} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: This question addresses a different topic in my opinion. The other question is not about probability mass functions.

Comment: Think about what $X$ means and how it can happen. That question calculates almost everything for you. Also, please show how you got your answers, not just a numerical value. Formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I think I found the answer, indeed with also looking at the other question + answer. But I don't know if I'm missing something.